# Foundation 6 Sticky layout broken in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, sticky, zurb-foundation-6

I found a tricky problem when using Sticky on Foundation 6.4.3. The sticky container will drop way down the page, and making a big gap between it and the anchor container. Anyone have this problem also?

Screen Capture
[Foundation 6 Sticky layout broken in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHY3n.png)

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css"/>
    
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="small-12 large-9 cell" id="sidebar-anchor">
          <div style="height: 900px; background-color: purple; ">
            main column
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 large-3 cell">
          <div data-sticky-container>
            <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="1" data-sticky-on="large" data-anchor="sidebar-anchor">
              <div style="height: 500px; background-color: yellow; ">
                sidebar
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/what-input/5.0.5/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use the `zurb-foundation` and `zurb-foundation-6` tags. `foundation` is not related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `position:sticky` on the yellow background div.

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css"/>
    
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="small-12 large-9 cell" id="sidebar-anchor">
          <div style="height: 900px; background-color: purple; ">
            main column
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 large-3 cell">
          <div data-sticky-container>
            <div class="sticky" data-sticky data-margin-top="1" data-sticky-on="large" data-anchor="sidebar-anchor" style="position:sticky">
              <div style="height: 500px; background-color: yellow; ">
                sidebar
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/what-input/5.0.5/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```